# Coded SWF Properties in Flash Builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, metadata, flash-builder, flexbuilder

i want to add a SWF metadata tag to an ActionScript Project in Flash Builder 4, that denotes the default size and background color of the swf.

i can do this in Flash Professional, but it doesn't work with ActionScript projects in FB4?  can i not include this tag?  i know i can set these properties in the properties panel, but i'd like to have them in my code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh, never mind.  dumb move on my part.  this metadata tag needs to be place just before the class declaration.

```
[SWF(width="1800", height="600", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#0")]
public class Test extends Sprite
     {
     ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it seems to throw a *warning* in Flash Builder 4.7

To resolve the warning, the meta data line must precede directly before the Class function.

```
package{
    import xyz;

    [SWF(width='640',height='480',backgroundColor='#6cf354',frameRate='25')]
    public class main extends Sprite {
```